# Redirect 404 URL to search page with htaccess and pass that 404 url as keywords to search page

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-404

I want to redirect 404 page to search page.

For example,

`example.com/url` - if this url is not found then redirect the url in the format:

```
example.com/index.php?page=search/web&search=[url]&type=Web&fl=0
```

It has to be done with htaccess.  I was not able to achieve this with htaccess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following rule in root/htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine On


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php?page=search/web&search=$1&type=Web&fl=0 [NC,L,R=301]
```

Comment: will it only redirect 404? how to add 301 code in this redirect?

Comment: will it only redirect 404? how to add 301 code in this redirect?